# When I dynamically load data into my uitableviewcontroller, my separator insets default back

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` that I am trying to do a pull refresh with.  In my `viewDidLoad` method I set the SeparatorInsets to 0

```
 override func viewDidLoad(){
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero


    }
```

At first the separators look correct, but as soon as i dynamically add any `UITableViewCell`'s to the table, the ones added have a separator inset. I am calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` and loading cells like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

        let cell:MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myTableCell") as MyTableViewCell

            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero


        return cell
    }
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I have also changed the custom separator inset interface builder

Comment: Is it a single Cell are you using for both the layout?

Comment: Can you try adding "cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero" into tableView:willDisplayCell: ?

Comment: Do you use "UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine" or "UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched"?

Answer (score 0):

Write Your cell property in this method. May be it is helpful.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
  cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

}
```